# How to execute shell command without double Quotes

Tags: vb6

I need to execute the below command in command prompt using vb6,
quser /server:machinename
So my code is,

```
mycommand = "quser / server: & strString" 'where strstring will be my machine name..
Shell "cmd.exe" & mycommand
```

The problem is it is executing in command prompt with the double quotes. But if double quotes is there, I wont get the expected results. I need to execute the above without double quotes. 
Please let me know your comments.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: I just realised now, you have loads of questions where people did all the work to help you solved you issues, you never respond or mark any as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use double double quotes to encode a double quote in a vb6 string.

e.g.

```
Dim str as String
str = "This is some text with a " & """double quote""" & "in it."
MsgBox str
```

Will show a message: This is some text with a "double quote" in it.

This is what I think you want:

```
mycommand = """quser / server:" & strString & """"
Shell "cmd.exe " & mycommand
```

Note that you did not have a space after cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I can see is that your last double quote is in the wrong place and so 
mycommand is just the string `"quser / server: & strString"`.

To append the value of a variable called strString to the end of the string you would use

```
mycommand = "quser / server:" & strString
```

The next problem is that there needs to be a space between cmd.exe and the parameters string.
Either replace "quser... with " quser... or replace "cmd.exe" with "cmd.exe "