# How do I run a command line in vb6?

Tags: command-line, vb6

I am trying to run a command line in vb6 and it won't work because of a `"` character in the command.

Here is the code I can run in command line and it works but when doing it from the VB it gets screwed up.

`AlarmSummaryUtility 10 TP=1;PT=4 "W h:m:s:F:p" /export`

Following is VB script that does not work because I think the command already has `""` around the one section:

```vb
Dim command As String
command = AlarmSummaryUtility 10 TP=1;PT=4 "W h:m:s:F:p" /export
shell "CMD.exe /c " & command
End Sub
```

The issue is that in the command I am trying to execute, it already has `"W h:m:s:F:p"`.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398713/how-to-execute-shell-command-without-double-quotes

Comment: Also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035618/how-to-call-the-command-line-in-vb6

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the quote with double quotes.

```
Dim command As String

command = "AlarmSummaryUtility 10 TP=1;PT=4 ""W h:m:s:F:p"" /export"
```

Comment: Thank you!  What if I want to add another command on the same line.  I need to change directory first and then run the above command.  Would I do the following with the & symbol?  "cd c:\deltav\bin" & etc.

Comment: `&` converts and combines strings.  For commands, I think you need to execute one and then the other. Or, you can just add the path to the original commands and have a single command.  You can use & to make it more readable.

Comment: You can only combine commands if that would actually work on the real command line.